# Optimise user data fetch using S3

Tags: security, rest, amazon-s3

I'm writing a mobile app that communicates with my server using REST.
Upon every launch, the app makes a call to the server api to check whether there was a change in the user details (using a `lastUpdate` parameter), the api returns the updated user object in case there was a change.

**Problem**

The drawback to this approach of course, is that every launch of the app causes an api call (and an SQL query) to my server.

**Solution**

I had an idea to use `HTTP ETAG\last-modified header` and store the user details as a json file in S3 bucket (+ S3 access control). That way, the app can check against that file (instead of a direct call to the api). I will save lots of connections to my server and lots of db queries as well.

**Question**

It seems like a legit solution, though somehow I get the feeling that storing all my users data in files on S3, is not secure..

What do you think?

Comment: Seems workable but a little sketchy. :)  Doesn't the app need to authenticate itself to you every time the user launches the app?  If it does, then you could just return that lastUpdate value as part of the authentication response.  If not, why not?

Comment: The app uses another call to authenticate itself. I think adding `lastUpdate` to a different, unrelated call, is a good solution. Not to mention it won't save the db queries.

Comment: It won't save on db queries?  Or it will?  I was working under the assumption that authentication required you to hit the database, and you could grab the lastUpdate info at the same time.

Comment: It will require a different query to the db.